# Microsoft Graph Communications - Bot joining call - Microsoft Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Ok.  So let me try to set the stage here.

I have a Microsoft Teams Application that has a Bot (Bot Framework v4) associated with it.

I have a use case where when a specific type of compliance activity happens, I need my bot to join the scheduled meeting and participate.

I am able to send a meeting invitation to an email account associated with the bot, and the bot accepts the invite.

According to this documentation, I should be able to join the meeting in progress.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) - Specifically "Example 5"

According to what I am reading, once you have the required Graph Permissions on your App Id that's associated, you only need 3 pieces of information to join the call (Passed in through a communications/call/create).

Post to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/calls :

Body:

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call",
  "callbackUri": "https://bot.contoso.com/callback",
  "requestedModalities": [
    "audio"
  ],
  "mediaConfig": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.serviceHostedMediaConfig",
    "preFetchMedia": []
  },
  "chatInfo": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.chatInfo",
    "threadId": "19:meeting_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@thread.v2",
    "messageId": "0"
  },
  "meetingInfo": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.organizerMeetingInfo",
    "organizer": {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet",
      "user": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identity",
        "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "tenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "displayName": "Drew Jenkel"
      }
    },
    "tenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "allowConversationWithoutHost": true
  }
}
```

Upon doing this, I'm getting a 403 / Forbidden:

```
{
 "error": {
   "code": "7505",
   "message": "Request authorization tenant mismatch.",
   "innerError": {
     "request-id": "30739bd2-37b2-4bfc-9c52-36d72a4aa54e",
     "date": "2020-06-08T16:47:36"
   }
 }
}
```

Has anyone seen anything this this?

Comment: is the bots app tenancy the same as the meeting organiser tenancy? seemed like an odd restriction to me (as i'd love a bot that can join external meetings) but afaik the restriction exists.

Comment: can i do this without graph,my tenancy have disabled graph permissions